# Solving $\frac{9a^3-7ab^2+2b^3}{3a+2b}=3a^2-2ab-b^2+\frac{4b^3}{3a+2b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following problem:

$$\frac{9a^3-7ab^2+2b^3}{3a+2b}$$

The solution in the book is

$$3a^2-2ab-b^2+\frac{4b^3}{3a+2b}$$

but I do not know how to get there. I could solve the other exercises and have thought that the solution would be

$$3a^2+b^2-2ab-\frac{6ab^2}{3a+2b}.$$

For which terms do I have to search, to find some more examples of such exercises?

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: have you done algebraic division? My latex skills is not strong when it comes to formatting this process..so until someone gives you an answer, I would say look at that topic on google.

Comment: Try to do long division and eliminate a.

Comment: I think that your answer can be represented as $3a^2-2ab+2b-b^2$

Comment: @Antony should the : symbol instead be $\div$?

Comment: I*ve got answer $3a^2-2ab-b^2$.

Comment: @John Molokach , yes , I miss it.

Comment: Thanks, with long division I've got the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution in the book is not correct (typo, I guess). If you perform the long division, you should get $$\frac{9a^3 - 7ab^2 + 2b^3} {3a + 2b}=3a^2-2ab-b^2+\frac{4b^3}{3a+2b}$$